# Python - Advanced string escaping

Tags: python

I have a string in python. I used escape() to get rid of the newlines, now my string looks like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;Wie hoch ist der Anteil &amp;laquo;oraler MS-Medikamente&amp;raquo;
bei Neuverschreibungen in Ihrer Sprechstunde?&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

But its supposed to look like this

```
Wie hoch ist der Anteil oraler MS-Medikamente bei Neuverschreibungen in Ihrer Sprechstunde?
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to decode (reverse escape).
   HTML Encoder / Decoder - Converts characters to their corresponding HTML Entities - Web 2.0 Generators http://goo.gl/2tcml1
2. You could use also this hint

```python
import BeautifulSoup

soup= BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
cleantext = soup.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *unescape* the string in order to get HTML tags back:

```
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
str = parser.unescape(str)
```

and then use some regex to remove HTML tags:

```
p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
return p.sub('', str)
```

I don't really recommend using regexes for parsing HTML, you can use `BeautifulSoup` instead.

Answer (score 0):

List all unnecessary symbols in the *characters* list and then replace them:

```
string = '&lt;p&gt;Wie hoch ist der Anteil &amp;laquo;oraler MS-Medikamente&amp;raquo;bei Neuverschreibungen in Ihrer Sprechstunde?&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;'

def unescape(s):
    characters = ["&lt;p&gt;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&amp;", "laquo;", "raquo;", "nbsp;", "/p"]
    for character in characters:
        s = s.replace(character, "")
    return s

print(unescape(string))
```

Here is the result:

> Wie hoch ist der Anteil oraler MS-Medikamentebei Neuverschreibungen in
>   Ihrer Sprechstunde?